# Adding modal changes layout

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, modal-dialog

I have made a modal with the following code:
The modal works fine, but the problem is that it changes the layout of the topbar and header position when I go to the page where the modal is placed. On the other pages the topbar and header are still like they should be.
What is the problem?

Thanks

```
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.0/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
</head>

<body>

<!-- Button trigger modal -->
<a data-toggle="modal" href="#myModal" class="btn btn-default btn-xs" >Size chart</a>

<!-- Modal -->
<div class="modal fade" id="myModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
<div class="modal-dialog">
  <div class="modal-content">
    <div class="modal-header">
      <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">&times;</button>
      <h4 class="modal-title">Modal title</h4>
    </div>
    <div class="modal-body">
        <img class="img-responsive" src="http://vmatechs.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/07/android.jpg" alt="image" />
    </div>
    <div class="modal-footer">
      <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
      <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Save changes</button>
    </div>
  </div><!-- /.modal-content -->
</div><!-- /.modal-dialog -->
 </div><!-- /.modal -->  
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<body>
```

[image: modal changes]

Comment: add your code js fiddle

Comment: Hi, I don't know how to do that?

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/3r0nggvh/

Comment: I tried but I have no clue what to do with the links

Comment: check second link

Comment: you mean bootstrap-theme.min.css">?

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/3r0nggvh/#&togetherjs=5ORjK7uksF

Comment: This is not a complete code what u had posten in question please post the complete code

Comment: This is the complete code for the working modal